# Nuxt.js (Vue.js): How to handle subdomains?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, subdomain, wildcard, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt.js (vue.js) app. Since nuxt automatically generate routes based on directory structure within `pages` folder. I was wondering how it would handle subdomains.

I want to create a folder named `pages/subdomains` and want to redirect all subdomains to this folder. How can I achieve this via Nuxt?

Answer (score 1):

this might not have existed when you first asked, but it looks like there's a module 'k-domains' that can solve this.

https://morioh.com/p/4b2454c8897c

Easy to use, for example:

```
  export default {
    buildModules: [
      [ "k-domains", {
          subDomains: ["blog", "projects", "anotherSubDomain" ], // List of directories to hold te pages for your subdomains
          rootDomain: "main-domain" //  directory to hold the pages for root domain  
      }
      ],
      ["@nuxtjs/router",{
          keepDefaultRouter: true // this line is mandatory...
      }
      ]
    ]
}
```

with a file tree like:

```
|   
|─pages
|   ├───blog
|   ├───projects
|   ├───main-domain
|   └───anotherSubDomain
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you want?
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#base

Add this code in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/pages/subdomains/'
  }
}
```